# Compiling two footer related javascripts

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript to load the footer of my website and another to dynamically check the current year and display it with the copyright. Is it possible to do this in one function?

***load-footer.js***

```
$(function(){
   $("#footer").load("footer.html");
});
```

***get-year.js***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yearfooter').text(new Date().getFullYear());
});
```

Comment: I am assuming that `#yearfooter` is in `footer.html`. If so, why don't you just load `get-year.js` inside `footer.html`?

Comment: That works. But I'm trying to keep this is one js file. I want to know if it is possible to put this two together in one function

Comment: You know `.load()` has a callback `function` , right? http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But you have to make sure that `footer.html` has been loaded.

You can do it like,

```
$(function(){
   $("#footer").load("footer.html", function() {
      // footer.html has been loaded.
      $('#yearfooter').text(new Date().getFullYear());
   });
});
```

Comment: When I do it this way, my footer doesnt appear in the page at all

Comment: @MichelleAshwini Sorry, i forgot to enclose the curly bracket. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works now. I had forgotten a semicolon. :)

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.load` method accepts callback function, so you can put year modification there:

```
$(function(){
    $("#footer").load("footer.html", function () {
        $('#yearfooter').text(new Date().getFullYear());
    });
});
```

Read more at: http://api.jquery.com/load/